# How to render component somewhere other than where it is called in the DOM

Tags: angular

In the olden days of JavaScript, we would often place DOM elements with IDs or classes where we wanted certain pieces of functionality and then use global JavaScript code to inject that functionality dynamically into each one.

This allowed for functionality to be injected where it was needed in the DOM, regardless of the position of the script calling it.

Granted we have moved away from this paradigm today, especially with the advent of Angular 2/4.  And this is where I am running into a slight problem.  **I need a way to render an Angular 2/4 component somewhere other than where the selector tag was inserted into the DOM.**

This is specifically so that I can position a popover absolutely without any other relatively positioned parent elements affecting the positioning.  Unfortunately I do not have the power to ensure that no parent elements have a relative positioning, or I would just take that approach.  And sadly there is no CSS way to ignore relatively positioned parent elements.

**Is there a way to make Angular inject the template for a given element in a particular location in the DOM?**  In this instance I'd be looking to load this either directly into the content section of the page or directly before the closing body tag, regardless of where the selector tag is in the DOM.

I looked into **DynamicComponentLoader**, but this seems to have been deprecated.  It looked promising but I can't find an alternative.  Can anybody point me in the direction of a way to do this? Is there even one?

Comment: Do you have control over the entire codebase, and is your template an angular one? If so, I recommend just adding <my-modal-window> component to your root component. Within that component you can control which template loads when and how

Comment: I do have control over the entire code based up to the layout which determines where the content for an application is loaded.  Ideally I would be able to put a section next to the content section that would allow things like this tooltips to be rendered there outside of any other layouts.  Would you be able to provide an example of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to include a component in your main app component, and have it take an input to show or hide that can be passed in, code sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcst8j

Depending on your needs you can make this much more complex. Eventually if you end up with a larger application, it would be best to consider a state management strategy to how you can handle complex state management: https://bertrandg.github.io/angular2-application-state-management-strategy/ I personally have elected to go with ngrx[https://github.com/ngrx/platform]. I see a lot of the industry is gearing towards Redux and redux-style stage management. There are a lot of options.